# Explaining rotation without mathematics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force

I understand why an object rotates about its centre of mass from a mathematical perspective but I have been trying to think how we can explain this in terms of the bonds within the object.  Feel free to amend this example to help explain, but I was thinking about a linear molecule that receives a force for a brief time at right angles to the axis of its bond. I think it is the bond that provides the centripetal force to cause the circular motion of the particle that was initially ‘pushed’, let’s say the right atom. And if this is the case then I am happy that by Newton’s third law the atom at the opposite end (left side) of the molecule will have its centripetal force, also from the bond, to cause its circular motion, but how is the initial upwards force on the first atom translated to a downward force on the left atom to get it moving in the first place? As you need an initial perpendicular velocity to the centripetal force to get circular motion?
[image]

If physics only has a mathematical explanation for this phenomenon, or that ‘we observe it to be the case so that’s what happens’, and it cannot be explained by the particle model of matter then please do just state that.

Comment: I think yeah, iirc you consider the molecule as a rigid rotor or something like the bond is like a rod connecting two hard spheres, so if you give it a spin around com then since the balls are stuck to ends, it must rotate with the rod due to tension

Comment: I don't fully understand why you think the other mass needs a downward force acting on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like to avoid mathematics, you can always break down the process into a series of steps.

1. Say you apply an upward force to the atom on the right for a very short time, the atom on the right will gain some momentum. Meanwhile the atom on the left is still stationary during this time. It hasn't felt the effects immediately. Information travels at the speed of light.
2. The right atom will move up. When the right atom moves up, the bond stretches. This causes the atom on the left to experience a component of **upward** force also a component of force to the right. Essentially, the left atom moves up during this small time at the start. This is expected, you apply a force on an object you at least expect the centre of mass motion to move in the direction of the force, not the opposite.
3. Since your force is off centre of mass then your combined system will also rotate about the center of mass. As I explained above you will also have other components of force not just up and down. The bond is changing orientation with time. Factoring in that the atoms are moving as well. These forces (including the up and down) will contribute the oscillation of the atoms in a 2D plane. This results in rotation.

So after going through this process what we have determined is that centre of mass moves upwards however you will get also get rotation.

The 2nd picture you have drawn in the image is actually in the centre of mass frame of reference. (i.e. you are moving with the centre of mass). In the stationary frame both atoms will ultimately move upwards.

Please let me know if I have answered your question or if you would like clarification.

Edit: Additional sketch for clarification. The image shows the state of the system at different times $t_{3}>t_{2}>t_{1}>0$. At each time step I show the force due the bonding and the velocity that resulted from the prior time. Then I show the new velocity vector.For the next time, I displace the atoms in the direction the new velocity vector is pointing. I do this for a couple of times to demonstrate that you will end up getting rotation. Also I assumed I am working in the centre of mass frame when I sketched these diagram.

Also for $t_{3}$ I accidentally displaced the atoms in the same time step. The velocity directions are correct however the displacement occurs in the next time step.
[image]

Comment: "*Information travels at the speed of light.*" Not necessarily. Plus I think the OP might be interested in a rigid system

Comment: Either way speed of sound or speed of light. It takes time for things to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, I’m happy that the centre of mass would move up as well but it’s how the bond transmits a force that causes the left atom to gain the velocity indicated in the diagram when the initial push is upwards. It’s intuitive to know that it would happen, but I can’t work out why

Comment: If the bond behaves like a spring (which is acceptable for small oscillations), then the bond only exerts forces along the line connecting the two atoms. The misunderstanding here is which inertial frame of reference you are dealing with. In the centre of mass frame your masses will rotate as you have indicated. If you are in the rest from where the centre of mass is moving up, both atoms will be moving upwards, however they will have a relative velocity for example, the atom on the right might have v_cm+v, while the atom on the left has v_cm-v.

Comment: The part I still don’t get is why, in both frames of reference, the left atom starts to rotate.  For circular motion we need an initial velocity perpendicular to the centripetal force and for the left atom’s direction of rotation we know that must be downwards (if we are just talking about the centre of mass frame now)  Without this initial velocity the left atom would just move upwards due to the force from the bond and not rotate. As soon as I can see where this initial downward velocity comes from then I can see that the force of the bond acts as the centripetal force for circular motion

Comment: I will edit the answer above with an sketch of the system at different time steps. At each time step I will draw the force due to the bonds also the current velocity of each atom and I will also draw the new velocity vector. Recall that the force is proportional to the change in velocity. For example, $\vec{v}_{t+\Delta t}=\vec{v}_{t}+\vec{F} \Delta t/m$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed drawing and taking the time to reply. I can see from your diagram that the left atom (the only one I cannot reconcile with circular motion) would not take a linear path. However, if I were to draw the actual ‘orbit’ of the left atom it would trace the same path as the right atom and as such in your t1 diagram the left atom should be moving down and right rather than up and right - it should be moving from the 9 o’clock position anti-clockwise through to the 6 o’clock position. Which your force diagram does not give...unless I mistaken

Comment: When the right atom gets a push, the bond between the left and right atom gets slightly stretched. This induces the tension force pulling the atoms back together as I have indicated. Since the left atom is initially at rest, it will move in this direction.